# select query is slow

Tags: java, mysql, sql, performance

I have a table in my sql with a 1000 of data and I am using the following sql query

```
select entityID,name from entity where DataItemId=2020
```

but it takes around 40 or 50 sec to extract the data and it is not acceptable

Comment: There can be many factor, but a good starting point is to index your column `DataItemId`, if not

Comment: Add index on DataItemId field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create an index on the DataItemId column.

see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html

This type of query should have sub-second performance

Answer (score 1):

To improve performance, create an `index` on DataItemId. If DataItemId is the identity column, make it the `primary key`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an Index on your search column if it is not the primary key column. It will increase the performance
Check this for [MySQL Indexing](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html)